# SSRS report exporting as PPT file

Tags: reporting-services, export, powerpoint

I have a SSRS report that I need to export as PPT file

In order to generate the slides, I put rectangles of the exact size of a slide in cm (33.867 x 19.05 cm), for each slide with the necessary content inside

There is a footer on each page (2cm) so each rectangle has a height of 17,05cm instead of 19,05

I removed margin and make sure report size is greater than body size

I don't know why but i'm not able to export it as I need, one rectangle for each page, there are always blank pages and first rectangle is printing on 2 pages for example

[image export ppt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJpIA.png)

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing the whole report design and position/size info for everything but a couple of things to check/try. Make sure your rectangle is all the way left (x = 0), also set the report property `ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace` to `True`.